# For $g \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, is it always true that $\lVert \Delta g \rVert_{H^{-1}} = \lVert \nabla g \rVert_{L^2}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces

Let $g \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we may define $\Delta g$ as an element of $H^{-1}$ by
\begin{equation}
\langle \Delta g, f \rangle_{H^{-1} \times H^1}:= -\langle \nabla g, \nabla f \rangle_{L^2}
\end{equation}

Then, I see that
\begin{equation}
\lvert \langle \Delta g, f \rangle_{H^{-1} \times H^1} \rvert \leq \lVert \nabla g \rVert_{L^2} \lVert \nabla f \rVert_{L^2} \leq \lVert \nabla g \rVert_{L^2} \lVert f \rVert_{H^1}
\end{equation}
implying that
\begin{equation}
\lVert \Delta g \rVert_{H^{-1}} = \lVert \nabla g \rVert_{L^2} \leq \lVert  g \rVert_{H^1}
\end{equation}

Could anyone please confirm that this is indeed correct? It is kind of surprising that a distribution can be bounded by the function from which it is derived..

Comment: you only proved $\|\Delta g\|_{H^{-1}} \le \|\nabla g\|_{L^2}$, otherwise the observation is correct.

Comment: The estimate is not so surprising as you have different norms on left and right hand-side.